# How to run a function as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, variables

I have a function called "LoadDataClassForImageClassification" and i dont want the user to type it again and again... I tried

```py
def LoadDataClassForImageClassification():
    print('Loading...')
    ## ML THINGS
x = LoadDataClassForImageClassification()
x()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a variable that it's value is the address of the function

```
def LoadDataClassForImageClassification():
     print('Loading...')

x = LoadDataClassForImageClassification
print(x) # <function LoadDataClassForImageClassification at 0x7f96363f11f0> # for example
x()
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot @dsasd! I will mark it correct but i have to wait 10 minutes before marking it correct

Comment: "location of" is rather misleading.